# Databinding to an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, observablecollection

The following in my code in MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
namespace Test
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public class ChannelInfo : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
            protected void Notify(string propertyName)
            {
                if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                {
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                }
            }
            private string _channelDescription;
            public string ChannelDescription
            {
                get
                {
                    return _channelDescription;
                }
                set
                {
                    if (value != _channelDescription)
                    {
                        _channelDescription = value;
                        Notify("ChannelDescription");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ChannelInfo> Channels { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Channels = new ObservableCollection<ChannelInfo>() 
            { 
                new ChannelInfo() { ChannelDescription = "Ib" } 
            };
            DataContext = Channels;
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //((ObservableCollection<ChannelInfo>)DataContext).Add(new ChannelInfo() { ChannelDescription = "Ib" });            
        }
    }
}
```

In my XAML I have a `TextBox` defined as follows:

```
<TextBox Height="23" Text="{Binding ChannelDescription}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="180,106,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
```

Now my problem is if I add an item to `Channels` in the constructor itself, then the `TextBox` is displaying the bound text. But when I add it in the `Window_Loaded` like above (uncomment the line), the Text is not displayed.

Comment: The Loaded event can be awkward because it has some behavioural anomalies.  Is there a need to hook Loaded as opposed to using the constructor?

Comment: I just tried this and I'm afraid to say that the items were displayed both when I added them from the constructor *and* when I added them from the `Loaded` event handler. Admittedly I just used an `ObservableCollection<int>` because I don't have details of your data type, but it worked just fine... maybe you should try it with `int` or `string` instances to see if that works for you... it *may* have something to do with your data type?

Comment: the DataType is ChannelInfo which contains a string property

Comment: You are not adding anything with that code; you are just creating a local variable `Channels`. If you don't reset the `DataContext` afterwards how do you expect the binding engine to start looking at it? And of course there is no need at all to create a new collection like this -- you can just do `((ObservableCollection<ChannelInfo>)DataContext).Add(...)`.

Comment: I edited my question. Maybe I was not clear.

Comment: @Jon: I tried what you suggested. I added the line to `Window_Loaded` event. But it's not working.

Comment: @Abhishek: This code does not even compile.

Comment: Let me edit my question completely.